# Search by key name in json array with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i retrieve only the key named "id" from my json array ?

```
$.each(data.tickets, function (key, data) {
        console.log(key)
        $.each(data, function (key, data) {
            console.log(key, data)
        })
    })
```

Here is what i get from my console log.[image]

and here is data.ticket :

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do... do you want an array containing only the ids

Comment: cayou include `data.tickets`?

Comment: `data.tickets.id`? It would have been a lot more helpful if you'd shown us the actual format of the response you receive from your AJAX request.

Comment: `var ids = $.map(data.tickets, function (data) { return data.id;})`

Comment: #Arun P johny can you put your comment as answer pls so i can validate it ? because it is the right answer thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can also do this without jQuery, `data.tickets.reduce(function(ids, obj){ return ids.concat(obj.id); }, [])`